# Unable to use Bluetooth on Ubuntu 14.04 64bit

Tags: 14.04, sound, bluetooth

I recently had a need to do a clean reinstall of my machine and for the most part things are working ok. However when trying to connect my BT headset (Noga NG-55BT, generic BT headset) I am unable to get any audio sent to the device. It registers just fine and machine detect's it but that is as far as it goes.

I looked into similar issues on this and other sites tried all kind of things and no luck.

OS: Ubuntu 14.04 64bit (Unity desktop)
Realteck WIFI ppa: ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi

Here is the hardware info:

```
hciconfig -a hci0

  hci0: Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
      BD Address: 54:27:1E:12:C7:F4  ACL MTU: 820:8  SCO MTU: 255:16
      UP RUNNING PSCAN 
      RX bytes:1365 acl:0 sco:0 events:143 errors:0
      TX bytes:26411 acl:0 sco:0 commands:142 errors:0
      Features: 0xff 0xfb 0xff 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
      Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
      Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF PARK 
      Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
      Name: 'darko-CX-Nice-Evo-II-0'
      Class: 0x6c0100
      Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Audio, Telephony
      Device Class: Computer, Uncategorized
      HCI Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Revision: 0xe3d
      LMP Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Subversion: 0xa5b1
      Manufacturer: Realtek Semiconductor Corporation (93)
```

sudo luusb

```
  Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
  Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
  Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
  Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
  Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
  Bus 001 Device 005: ID 13d3:3394 IMC Networks Bluetooth
  Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
  Bus 001 Device 006: ID 4c2d:2900  
  Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0ac8:c303 Z-Star Microelectronics Corp. Saturn USB 2.0 Camera
  Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0607 Genesys Logic, Inc. Logitech G110 Hub
  Bus 001 Device 007: ID 04f2:b3a3 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
  Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

sudo inxi -A

```
  Audio:     Card-1: Intel 8 Series/C220 Series High Definition Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel 
             Card-2: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel 
             Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture ver: k4.2.0-27-generic
```

dmesg | grep -i blue

```
  [    1.543904] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
  [    1.543937] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
  [    1.543940] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
  [    1.543942] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
  [    1.543961] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
  [    1.558606] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
  [    1.558614] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
  [    1.558619] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
  [    1.561643] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
  [    1.561649] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
  [    1.561654] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
  [    1.583902] usb 1-6: Product: RT Bluetooth Radio
  [    2.614983] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=1200
  [    2.614987] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723a_fw.bin
```

pactl list short | grep blue

```
  24    module-bluetooth-policy     
  25    module-bluetooth-discover
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please edit the question to include results for `pactl list short | grep blue`

Comment: Added the requested information